# Decompile XAPK file

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler

I have worked pretty a lot analyzing Android projects with different reverse engineering tools, generally for secure purposes, to see what can be seen by a hacker when he/she gets my app. I've met a problem that I couldn't find any of decompilers capable to decompile files of "XAPK" format (not simple APK).
I know, asking for a way to find a tool is not kind of questions good for stack overflow, but I am pretty sure there are many people with the same problem and I find it highly relevant.
I tried [apk-tool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), decompilers provided with [androguard](https://code.google.com/archive/p/androguard/) tool, online-decompilers, none of them are capable of working with XAPKs.

Comment: @Antimony That's an apk file, wihch contains also obb file (opaque binary blob) related to an application in apk file. This kind of files are generally used by different apk-download sevices, like https://apkpure.com/xapk.htm

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `.xapk` is just a ZIP file which contains the original `.apk` along with some other files. You can simply unzip the `.xapk` and decompile the `.apk` within.

For more details, there's [Decompiling XAPK Files](http://calebfenton.github.io/2016/02/28/decompiling-xapk-files/).

Comment: how do I put it back together, then?

Comment: Looking at the blogpost you could zip it in the original order, and it would be good to go.

The only difference from my case was that i got 2 apks, rather than 1. One for the actual application, and second one called "config.arm64_v8a.apk". Looks like the latter is only native libraries.